# I can not access to mount directory from Django when using docker

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume, docker-container

I run Django in docker and I want to read a file from host. I mount a path in host to container using following command in my docker-compose file:

```
volumes:     
      - /path/on/host/sharedV:/var/www/project/src/shV
```

Then I execute mongodump and export a collection into sharedV on host. After that, I inspect web container and go to the **shV** directory in container and I can see the backup file. However,  when I run `os.listdir(path)` in django, the result is empty list. In the other word, I can access to **sharedV** directory in Django but I can not see its contents!
Here is the Mount part of container inspect:

```
"Mounts": [           
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/path/on/host/sharedV",
                "Destination": "/var/www/project/src/shV",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ]
```

Is there any idea that how can I access to host from a running container?

thanks

Comment: That is the way to access the shared directory. Can it be a permissions problem? WHat are the permissions on the folder and the file you want to access? Sometimes windows permissions do not translate well to linux permissions ... '

Comment: My os is ubuntu and the sharedV has read and write access.

Comment: The left-side part must be *real* path, not "/path/on/host/sharedV" - verity within your Ubuntu where your real location is and provide it - for example `./dir:/var/www/project/src/sharedV` where `./dir` is in your current directory where your **docker-compose.yml** is located - if you know absolute path specify it. Of course it will not know what "path on host" means.

Comment: Tnx @urbanespaceman. I added Mount part of container inspect to question.

Comment: Thanks @dmitryro. The "/path/on/host/sharedV" is a real path in my ubuntu. As I said, when I run "docker exec -it container bash" and go to web container, I can see "shv" folder and also its content(exported file). However, when I run os.listdir(path) from django the content of "shv"  is empty!

Comment: your actual *Dockerfile* you might also need `RUN chmod +x /yourvolume` - look at https://chameth.com/understanding-docker-volume-mounts/ - it looks like permissions issue on a volume that was not properly mounted and made accessible.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, Tying to give you a perception
Project Tree

```
.
├── app
│   ├── dir
│   ├── file.txt
│   └── main.py
├── dir
│   └── demo.txt
├── docker-compose.yml
└── Dockerfile
```

Dockerfile

```
# Dockerfile
FROM python:3.7-buster
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
        
RUN useradd appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser
        
CMD [ "python", "./main.py" ]
```

docker-compose

```
version: '2'

services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app/
      - ./dir:/app/dir
```

main.py

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = './dir'
    dir = os.listdir(path)
    print(f'Hello', dir)
```

Prints

```
Hello ['demo.txt']
```